# Is this description of "ordinary induction" from Velleman's *How to Prove It* correct?

Tags: induction, definition, proof-theory

The following is from [How to Prove It: A Structured Approach, 2nd edition](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/how-to-prove-it/97F48414AF68062CCE4BBACBA3DDE1E9), by Daniel J. Velleman, page 289.

> To see why strong induction works, it might help if we first review briefly why
>   ordinary induction works. Recall that a proof by ordinary induction enables us
>   to go through all the natural numbers in order and see that each of them has
>   some property $P$. The base case gets the process started, and the induction step
>   shows that the process can always be continued from one number to the next.
>   But note that in this process, by the time we check that some natural number
>   $n$ has the property $P$, we've already checked that *all smaller numbers* have the property. In other words, we already know that $∀k < nP(k)$. The idea behind
>   strong induction is that we should be allowed to use this information in our
>   proof of $P(n)$.

That characterization of "ordinary induction" is certainly not how I think of standard (not strong) complete induction.  I think of it as showing that $P\left[1\right]$ holds (the *initial case*) and then showing that $P\left[n\right]\implies{P\left[n+1\right]}$, where $P\left[n\right]$ is called the *induction hypothesis*, and $P\left[n\right]\mapsto{P\left[n+1\right]}$ is the *induction step*.

Are these characterizations of complete induction mutually contradictory?  Are they essentially the same?

Comment: You probably need to explain your concern a little better. There are two forms of (ordinary) mathematical induction, a weak form and a strong form. Velleman is talking about both of them, and you're talking about one of them. Is your concern the use of the terms, or why the seemingly stronger version is equivalent to the weaker version, or something else? Part of the problem is that you say "mutually contradictory". What does "mutually" contribute to simply being contradictory? Also, if P implies Q but Q does not imply P (what I think you're saying), that doesn't make "P and Q" always false.

Comment: I added some clarification, but my original question seemed pretty clear to me.

Comment: It's not clear to me, because "*The base case gets ...*" is a fairly standard way of describing what weak induction involves. See the search results for [induction + ladder](https://www.google.com/search?q=induction+ladder) *AND* [induction + dominoes](https://www.google.com/search?q=induction+dominoes). Maybe you're concern is the variable shift from $n$ to $n+1?$ Note that $(\forall n)( P[n] \implies P[n+1])$ is the same as $(\forall n)( P[n+2] \implies P[n+3])$ (modulo appropriate restrictions on the values taken by $n).$

Comment: The consequence of complete induction (Peano's 5th axiom) is that all those cases are true, but it is not the method of proof to move sequentially from one to the next.  We prove the initial case and prove that the property is hereditary.  The rest follows.

Comment: I'm still a bit unclear what the problem is, unless it's a specific method of formalizing the notion, such as functions being "rules of correspondence" vs. "subsets of a Cartesian product". Also, Velleman is explaining things in [natural language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language) at this point, and so he's not trying to adhere to any strict method of formalization.

Comment: See [Complete (or strong) induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction) : "Complete induction is equivalent to ordinary mathematical induction".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That is not the definition I learned.  Peano's 5th axiom is the *principle of complete induction*.  It is given that name to distinguish it from the human language definition of the word induction which is by definition incomplete.  Complete induction proves in one stroke a proposition to be true for all natural number.

Comment: @StevenHatton That's the same thing - *nobody* here is using the natural language version of the word. Ordinary and strong induction are two forms of mathematical induction, which are equivalent in a precise sense.

Comment: [These lecture slides](http://www.cs.bath.ac.uk/~gam23/teaching/DiscreteMaths/03induction.pdf) look pretty good and might be helpful, especially pages 5 and 10-12.

Comment: Dave Renfro's comment is exactly right: Vellman is giving an *informal description* of the idea behind (the usual phrasing of) mathematical induction. It's not literally an infinite process, of course, but one can think of the induction axiom as somehow "compressing" what would normally be an infinite process into a single step (fine, two steps). Is this a *good* informal description? Maybe - in my experience it's usually helpful but sometimes confusing. Is it a *potentially mathematically useful* one? In my opinion, yes (at least in some areas of mathematical logic). Just don't over-think it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Apparently others distinguish between what I have been calling *standard complete induction* and *strong induction*.  From what I know, the latter is a consequence of the former.

Comment: @StevenHatton Yes, but so? Nowhere in this does natural-language induction appear. I really don't understand what your question is. As far as I can tell, all the relevant points are: $(i)$ what you call "standard complete induction" is often called "weak induction," is on-the-surface distinct from the thing called "strong induction," but is actually equivalent to it (in a precise sense); $(ii)$ both weak and strong induction are *mathematical principles*, not natural-language ideas; $(iii)$ Vellman's infinite-process description is just informal motivation. What does the above **not** address?

Comment: @NoahSchweber my point in referring to the natural language definition was to explain why mathematical induction is called *complete* induction.  In a situation in which I am applying induction, the first time I encounter the arbitrary number $n$ I determine if the target proposition is hereditary.  Velleman's description makes it seem as if I will always be reaching a new $n$ in an indeterminate state, and I can somehow leverage the previous results to prove the case of $n$.

Comment: Vellman is choosing to explain mathematical induction as essentially compressing an "infinite task" into an actual mathematical argument. This can in fact be made precise if one wants, so he's not just messing around, but that's beside the point: *it's just flavor.* If you don't like it, ignore it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Velleman's book has been otherwise lucid and pleasant to read, thus far.  (I skipped ahead to the section on strong induction in an effort comprehend the issues discussed here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3064870/342834 I honestly believe Velleman's characterization of "ordinary induction" is misleading, and could have been stated more accurately and effectively.  I believe I now understand the essence of what he was getting at.  That understanding would not have come from continuing to bleed over Behnke, Bachmann, Fladt, Suess.  The comments here have also been helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase "recall that" in the quoted paragraph makes it clear that this paragraph is referring back to an earlier explanation of why ordinary induction works.  It would be helpful to go back and look at that earlier explanation.  Induction is introduced on p. 260, and the definition is the usual one:  Prove $P(0)$ (the base case) and then prove $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}(P(n) \to P(n+1))$ (the induction step).  (Some people include 0 in the natural numbers and some don't.  In How To Prove It, 0 is included.)  On p. 262 there is an explanation of why induction works.  That explanation is that the base case proves that $P(0)$ is true.  Plugging in $n=0$ in the induction step you get $P(0) \to P(1)$, and from $P(0)$ and $P(0) \to P(1)$ you get $P(1)$.  Then plugging in $n=1$ in the induction step you get $P(1) \to P(2)$, and from $P(1)$ and $P(1) \to P(2)$ you get $P(2)$, etc.  The explanation ends with the statement "Continuing in this way, you should be able to see that by repeatedly applying the induction step you can show that $P(n)$ must be true for every natural number $n$."  When you carry out this process of starting with the base case and then repeatedly applying the induction step, you confirm first $P(0)$, then $P(1)$, then $P(2)$, and so on.  It is this process that I was referring to in the sentence "Recall that a proof by ordinary induction enables us to go through all the natural numbers in order and see that each of them has some property $P$."

Notice that the quoted passage says that mathematical induction *enables us* to go through all the natural numbers in order, it doesn't say that a proof by induction *consists of* going through the natural numbers in order.  A proof by induction consists of a base case and an induction step.  But if you've proven the base case and the induction step, then that would enable you to go through the natural numbers in order and verify that they all have property $P$, as described above.  And that's why induction works.  For example, if you've done a proof by induction, why is, say, $P(10)$ true?  The answer is that you have to start with $P(0)$ and apply the induction step 10 times to work your way from $P(0)$ up through $P(1)$, $P(2)$, and so on up to $P(10)$.