# Is this sufficient to prove the associativity of natural number addition?

Tags: proof-verification, induction, peano-axioms, natural-numbers

This question is regarding the same proposition as is discussed in [How should this proof of the associativity of natural number addition be understood?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3064870/342834)

Here I wish to ask if a much simpler proof than that provided by the book would suffice. We begin with the same starting point as in the other question:

A previously demonstrated result is:

\begin{equation}
\left(a+b\right)+c=a+\left(b+c\right). \tag{1}
\end{equation}

The following is quoted from [The Fundamentals of Mathematics, Volume 1](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/fundamentals-mathematics-3-vol-set):

> By (1) we may therefore omit the parentheses in a sum of three terms.
>   In order to be able to omit them in sums with more than three terms,
>   we first define the expression $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}$ for a given
>   sequence $\left\{ a_{i}\right\} _{i=1,2,\dots}$ of numbers $a_{i}$
>   recursively by setting
>
> \begin{equation}
> \sum_{i=1}^{1}a_{i}=a_{1},  \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}+a_{n+1};\tag{2}
> \end{equation}
>
> [$\dots$] In particular, we have $\sum_{i=1}^{3}a_{i}=\left(a_{1}+a_{2}\right)+a_{3}=a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{4}a_{i}=\left(a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}\right)+a_{4},$ for which we again naturally write $=a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}.$
>
> [$\dots$]

Can we not simply proceed as follows?

Assume

$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}=a_{1}+a_{2}+\dots+a_{n} \text{, and }S_n\in{\mathbb{N}}.$

Then argue

$S_{n+1}=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_{i}=S_n+a_{n+1}=a_{1}+a_{2}+\dots+a_{n+1}.$

Or even more simply by omitting the $\sum$ notation entirely, and argue that the result of the $n^{th}$ iteration is a natural number $S_n$ to which we apply the "we again naturally write" transformation in the $n+1^{th}$ step.

Will this not work?  If not, why not?

It may be the case that the author's of the book chose to do things the hard way to illustrate new concepts.

---

To address the specific question in the comments: what about $\left(a+b\right)+\left(c+d\right)$?
 I came up with this using the notation I invented to work on this problem:

Define the set of function:

$$
\Phi=\left\{ \varphi_{a\in\mathbb{N}}:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\backepsilon\varphi_{a}\left[x^{\prime}\right]\equiv\varphi_{a}\left[x\right]^{\prime}\land\varphi_{a}\left[1\right]\equiv a^{\prime}\right\} .
$$

To relate this to conventional notation we also define

$$
\left[\_+\right]:\mathbb{N}\to\Phi
$$

so that

$$
\left[a+\_\right]\equiv\varphi_{a},
$$

to be interpreted as
$$
a+b:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\text{ where }a+b\equiv\varphi_{a}\left[b\right].
$$

$$
\left(a+b\right)+c=\varphi_{a}\left[b\right]+c=\varphi_{a+b}\left[c\right]=a+b+c.
$$

$$
\left(a+b\right)+\left(c+d\right)=\varphi_{a}\left[b\right]+\varphi_{c}\left[d\right]
$$

$$
=\varphi_{a+b}\left[\varphi_{c}\left[d\right]\right]=\varphi_{a+b+c}\left[d\right]=a+b+c+d.
$$

I'm claiming to have justified treating every thing subscripted to $\varphi$ as a single number.

Comment: The authors of the book are at pains to carefully define what $\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ denotes; you are not.

Comment: Does you proof cover something like $$(a+b)+(c+d)=a+(b+c)+d=a+b+c+d$$ ?

Comment: @Peter That's something that has me puzzled.  For natural numbers, their sums will always be natural numbers.  So I'm wondering why I can't just replace $(a+b)$ by a natural number called $a+b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the addition without parentheses is a statement that we have the full power of associativity - that the sum will be the same no matter what we add first. If we don't have that theorem yet, then it's simply a more confusing shorthand for a particular standard order (in your referenced material, from left to right).

Your argument doesn't prove anything. All you have written is a definition. You've addressed how to go from $S_n$ to $S_{n+1}$ by adding one term, but not what happens if we add things in a different order so that it's some previous sum $S_k$ plus a sum of the last $n+1-k$ terms at the outermost layer of parentheses. Of course it will be the same - but we have to actually prove it, and it's not something that will work in one step from the associativity. There's a reason the proof in the book uses strong (modified, in the book's terminology) induction.

Comment: Superb answer !

Comment: I've pretty much figured out what the authors expect.  Now I need to figure out what it really means.